# Picasso: Image doesn't load when I add NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE

Tags: android, caching, picasso

I have this code to display an image to an ImageView holder:

```
Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(actContacts);
builder.listener(new Picasso.Listener()
{
  @Override
  public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception)
  {
    exception.printStackTrace();
  }
});
builder.build().load(pic).transform(new BitmapBorderTransformation(10, 100,      R.color.colorPrimary, 100, 100)).into(holder.imgIcon);
```

The code works fine when I am online.
When I add .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE) to display the image offline the image doesn't show at all (online or offline).

How can I display the image when offline?

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet :

```
Picasso.with(this)
            .load(pic)
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
            .into(holder.imgIcon);
```

Also Piccasso lets **HttpClient** handle the caching.

Try including [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) in your classpath , or resolve the caching manually.